# How to write this sentence in predicate logic?

Tags: logic

The question is write "Bob buys everything that is cheap" in predicate logic.
Following is my thought

∀x buy[Bob,cheap(x)]

I don't know whether it is true,but it is not the same with the answer.

Comment: No!  For an object $x$, "cheap(x)" is a "true/false". But Bob doesn't buy "true/false", Bob buys the object x.  So you need an implication between cheap(x) and buy(Bob,x).

Comment: @user10354138 I understand, thank you.